# Unable to wrap text in CSS to prevent text from overlapping

Tags: html, css, web, overflow, word-wrap

I need to wrap the text in my CSS file so that when it is viewed on a phone the text doesn't overlap (see screenshot below). I thought it would be as simple as adding **overflow-wrap: break-word;** and changing the height in **.skills .progress .skill** in but I've tried a number of combinations and can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

[Website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVk5Q.png)

HTML File - this is a Django project which calls the variables name and score from a model

```css
# Skills 

.skills .content h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #37517e;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.skills .content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.skills .content ul li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.skills .content ul i {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  color: #47b2e4;
}

.skills .content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.skills .progress {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: none;
}

.skills .progress .skill {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  width: 50vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #37517e;
}

.skills .progress .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
}

.skills .progress-bar-wrap {
  background: #e8edf5;
  width: 100vw;
}

.skills .progress-bar {
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  transition: .9s;
  background-color: #4668a2;
}

#skills {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills" class="skills">
  <div class="skills-content">
    <div class="progress">
      <span class="skill">{{Product.name}}&emsp; <i class="val">{{Product.score}}%</i></span>
      <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{Product.score}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I've also tried adding word-wrap: break-word

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@media (max-width: 650px) {}` that should do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine the exact root of the issue without seeing an accurate live version. However, I would try adding a `display: flex;` on the parent `#skills` and make your progress bar width `100vw`

```css
# Skills

.skills .content h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #37517e;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.skills .content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.skills .content ul li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.skills .content ul i {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  color: #47b2e4;
}

.skills .content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.skills .progress {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: none;  
}

.skills .progress .skill {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  width: 50vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #37517e;
}

.skills .progress .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
}

.skills .progress-bar-wrap {
  background: #e8edf5;
  width: 100vw;
}

.skills .progress-bar {
  width: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  transition: .9s;
  background-color: #4668a2;
}

#skills {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills" class="skills">
        <div class="skills-content">
                <div class="progress">
                    <span class="skill">{{Product.name}}&emsp; <i class="val">Social Media Marketing 100%</i></span>
                    <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{Product.score}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</section>
```